# Detecting the frequency /period of sine wave

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, trigonometry, atmega

I just need some guidance as to how to detect the frequency from a sine wave. I generated the sinewave via a DtoA converter. Now, I'm putting that signal back through an AtoD to monitor and verify the output.

I don't know how to detect the frequency of the sine wave. Apparently, I'm supposed to get the period from the sine wave and apply hysteresis to compensate for noise. 
Any hint is much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Did you try google? [Sine-Wave-Frequency-Detection](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Frequency-Detection/step3/Sine-Wave-Frequency-Detection/)

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. It is better suited for the [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) site. Nevertheless, you can use fast Fourier transform or autocorrelation, or even Goertzel algorithm, if you are looking for specific frequencies only.

Answer (score 2):

If this is about sine waves only, I'd check for zero crossings, and calculate the average time between zero crossings for a couple of hundred cycles, that would give an accurate half period length, and from that, you can calculate the frequency.

("zero" might not be trivial, as most uC have 0-Vdd range ADC inputs only, so zero in that case might happen to be Vdd/2...)

(very simple) pseudocode could be

```
const zero = 0; //or vdd/2 if that's the case
while(cyclesSoFar<enoughCycles) {
    currentSample=adcRead();
    //detect zero crossing (needs hysteresis added)
    if((lastSample>zero&&currentSample<=zero) || (lastSample<zero&&currentSample>=zero) ) {
        period = getTicks()-ticksAtLastCrossing; //might have to check for over/underflow to get correct value
        avgPeriod = avgPeriod * (cyclesSoFar)/(cyclesSoFar+1) + period/(cyclesSoFar+1);
        cyclesSoFar++;
    }
    lastSample = currentSample;
}
freq = ticksFreq/(avgPeriod*2);
```

Where: enoughCycles is the number of cycles to measure, zero is the DC offset of the sine wave, and ticksFreq is the frequency of the CPU, the most precise time available. Of course, this is very-very simplified, lots of fluff and checks need to be added.

Comment: 0 If the signal doesn't have an offset, but +1

Comment: thanks @ppeterka. can you please show me a pseudocode? i understand if you can't. thanks